# Change background color of a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying to change the color of a JFrame with no components inside it, but I can't seem to figure it out...

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setTitle("");
// Attempts to change the color
frame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
frame.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
// Attempts to change the color
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setResizable(false);  
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);` to set the color.

Answer (score -1):

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setTitle("");
// Attempts to change the color
frame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
frame.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
// Attempts to change the color
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setResizable(false);  
frame.setVisible(true);
```

You must use the frame as a undecorated jframe
The New Code Here

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
setUndecorated(true);
frame.setTitle("");
// Attempts to change the color
frame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
frame.setForeground(Color.BLACK); // by this code you haven't give a black foreground so remove this line 
// Attempts to change the color
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setResizable(false);  
frame.setVisible(true);
```

If you not want to undecorate JFrame

You can use a JPanel instead it.

Or use Answer No 1

But you can only use this `fr.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);` code in main method.

So Use this this answer's code.